# developer.salesforce.com guide shows errors

Tags: developer, documentation

I am having trouble accessing the salesforce developer guides (HTML version) 
It always shows this error to me :(

**Sorry, the document you are looking for doesn't exist or could not be retrieved**

Does anyone experience this, how to fix it? (I restarted my PC nothing happened)

Tried with Chrome and Firefox and in incognito mode always shows the error

For example this url : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/users_fields_fls.htm

Thanks

*For now I found a workaround I am using the Opera browser to access the salesforce documentation (but still having the trouble with Chrome and Firefox)*

[image]

Comment: What's the url shown in your browser? If you're using Google Chrome, try to press `Ctr+Shift+R`

Comment: This url for example : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/users_fields_fls.htm   I did that and I tried with firefox and on both with incognito mode but still shows the error

Comment: Did you try to press `Ctr+Shift+R`?

Comment: Yes, still nothing comes up, for now I always use the PDF version of the guide

Comment: Did this combination of key refresh your page?

Comment: Do you have javascript enabled? I believe the current iteration of the UI requires it.

Comment: On a semi-unrelated note...Salesforce performs over 100 http requests to reload a documentation page. For shame, Salesforce! It's little wonder why their current UI feels so pokey.

Comment: Yes I have Javascript Enabled, I thought that could the adblocker but on firefox I don't have Adblocker ....

Comment: i have seen this happen as well as a Japanese-themed doc appear from time-to-time; I've always assumed SFDC was in flight on some doc change as the problem always went away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same issue but finally found out why this was happening:
You probably have some add-on like "Adblock Plus" or "Ghostery" installed in your browser. If you deactivate **all** of them for [developer.salesforce.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/), then it should work again.

Comment: Thanks @Ata  solved for me on Chrome, I disabled the Adblocker for developer.salesforce.com and the error disappeared :)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with your computer (well, nothing that a restart would help at least). This is a deficiency (on Salesforce's part) of the newest documentation UI (user interface).

On some occasions, Salesforce will just simply fail to load documentation.

If you click a different section of the documentation, and click the section of documentation that you initially tried to visit again in the left-side menu, it should come up.

Refreshing the page in your browser may also work.

Comment: The highlighted item is not clickable for me :( when I click on the other items still the same error

Comment: In that case, try doing a page refresh that flushes the cache (ctrl + f5 in most browsers).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try again.
I can see the page you are looking for. (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/users_fields_fls.htm)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the screen shot, I was able to access the guides a week ago but now it's been 3 days that I have to use the PDF versions ...

Comment: haha.. ok.. better with pdf versions